Swiper JS wired behavior with lazy loading images in RTL direction
I have simple page here to show the problem. I'm using latest swiper version in RTL document to show some images slides as follow
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="eng" dir="rtl">
<head>
    <title>test swiper</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .swiper {
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .item-swiper-slide {
            width: 250px;
        }

        .item-swiper-slide:nth-child(n) {
            width: 250px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <div class="swiper">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide item-swiper-slide">
                <img loading="lazy" src="samlpe.jpg" width="250" height="300" alt="test"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide item-swiper-slide">
                <img loading="lazy" src="samlpe.jpg" width="250" height="300" alt="test"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide item-swiper-slide">
                <img loading="lazy" src="samlpe.jpg" width="250" height="300" alt="test"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide item-swiper-slide">
                <img loading="lazy" src="samlpe.jpg" width="250" height="300" alt="test"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide item-swiper-slide">
                <img loading="lazy" src="samlpe.jpg" width="250" height="300" alt="test"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide item-swiper-slide">
                <img loading="lazy" src="samlpe.jpg" width="250" height="300" alt="test"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide item-swiper-slide">
                <img loading="lazy" src="samlpe.jpg" width="250" height="300" alt="test"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide item-swiper-slide">
                <img loading="lazy" src="samlpe.jpg" width="250" height="300" alt="test"/>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide item-swiper-slide">
                <img loading="lazy" src="samlpe.jpg" width="250" height="300" alt="test"/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
    </div>
</main>
<script>
    const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
        loop: true,
        pagination: {
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
        scrollbar: {
            el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
        },
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>


as you can see it is a full function code that show some simple slides that all contains only one img tag that load in lazy mode. if you check this page you can see images not loaded until you scroll over slides to make them loaded. but I found that if you remove dir="rtl" from HTML tag, we can not see this problem.
additionally, I found that if i reduce number of slides to 2, 3 slides, it works without any problems. so i found that dir="rtl" and number of slides more than 2,3 items cause this problem. but i want to use it in RTL documents and my slides is more that 20 slides.
i should mention that you can see this problem only with chrome browser.
please help me to solve this problem.

Shouldn't you be adding lazy="true" on the slide elements (https://swiperjs.com/element#lazy), or lazy: true in your swiper options?

I just tried  them but didn't have any effect, and as i mentioned this code works well just by removing dir="rtl" from  tag

I just created a bug report here https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/7493 but still there isn't any feedback how fix this problem or when they release a version to fix this problem
